# Почему добавление элементов в SVG через JavaScript не работает?

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть скрипт, он добавляет в SVG круг, в саму HTML разметку этот кргу добавляется, можно проверить через отладчик, но у меня в браузере этот круг не выводится. То есть HTML обновилась но добавленные элементы не нарисовались.

При этом сам сгенерированный SVG - валидный, это можно проверить скопировав его из отладчика. Ещё проще можно проверить прямо в отладчике нажать редактировать HTML и добавить перед SVG например пробел и сохранить, круг сразу же появляется.

Почему так и как исправить?

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");

var circle = document.createElement("circle");

circle.setAttribute("cx", 110);
circle.setAttribute("cy", 20);
circle.setAttribute("r", 50);
circle.setAttribute("fill", "green");

svg.appendChild(circle);
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" style="width:400px; height:150px; background-color: pink;">
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="60" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Браузеры постоянно совершенствуются. Если раньше обязательно было объявлять `namespace` для svg кода:
 `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`,

то теперь этого можно не делать, будет работать, но не всегда должным образом.
Например, если вы напишите `viewbox` вместо правильного написания - "view**B**ox", то парсер не выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как для `HTML` нет разницы в каком регистре написаны буквы. Но для svg регистр чувствителен и команда не сработает.   Поэтому лучше всегда  указывать `namespace`.
Также и с командами `Javascript` для создания объектов `SVG`  Лучше всегда, вместо команды `setAttribute` использовать `setAttributeNS` для гарантированного кроссброузерного решения.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="400">
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    function createCircle() {
      var newCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",Math.random() * 100+250); 
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",Math.random() * 100+100);  
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",Math.random() * 100);  
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke",Math.random() * 100); 
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill-opacity",Math.random());  
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementById("firstCircle").appendChild(newCircle);
    } 
     
  ]]></script>
    <g id="firstCircle" onclick="createCircle()"> 
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="30" rx="10" fill="yellowgreen"  />
    <text x="64" y="40" fill="purple"  font-size="16px">Create a new circle.</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял, надо было с NS использовать.